# Bootstrap Center Scafolding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd have two "sections" in which I am using the bootstrap 3 scaffolding to style.  I am having a hard time figuring out how I might have these maintain their column spacing while still be centered on the middle of the page.  For example right now it is

```
<content><content>  ---<space>---
```

and i want

```
---<space>--- <content><content> ---<space>---
```

Here is what i've got.

```
<div class=".container-fluid" id="aboutContent">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="../imgs/pic.jpg" alt="Joe Brunett" id="aboutPicture"/>
    </div>
        <div class="well col-md-4" id="desc">   
            <p> text<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Offsets** can be used to center a `div` but remember that it'll work only for even columns

`<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"></div>`

You can even change the `break-point` by replacing

`<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>`

with

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"></div>`